# Howto easily install java libraries?

Tags: java

Is there some way to easily install and manage most of the common java libraries from a repository that are needed for an application, in a similar way that yum or apt-get or port work on unix/linux distributions?

For example, I would like to install org.apache.commons.lang3 and com.google.common.*

What is the easiest way to do that, on OS X?

Comment: I would recommend using [maven](http://maven.apache.org/) for that.

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/

Comment: Or, as a smaller tool, [Apache Ivy](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/) which can be easily integrated with ant.

Comment: Maven integration in IntelliJ IDEA is fantastic. Use that. Just type in your code (e.g.) `MultiSet m;` hit [alt-enter] > add Maven dependency...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Luiggi Mendoza recommended, [maven](http://maven.apache.org/) suits your needs. You can easily start to learn this technology [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html).

As you'll read in the last link, it will need you to create a `pom.xml` file. Then, you'll only have to add all your required dependencies in this file and maven will download them for you.

Most of well-known librairies can be found [this website](http://mvnrepository.com/).